# How to dynamic import a local typescript file

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

I have 2 files in the same folder. I want to dynamically import MyInterfaces.ts into index.ts.

```
// MyInterfaces.ts
export interface MyInterface1 {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

// index.ts
async function importMyInterfaces() {
  const myInterfaces = await import("./MyInterfaces");
  const data1: myInterfaces.MyInterface1 = {
    id: 1,
    name: "John Doe",
  };
}
```

I cannot figure how to achieve this without errors TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'myInterfaces'. I tried wrapping MyInterfaces.ts in a namespace but that didnt work either:

```
// MyInterfaces.ts
export namespace MyInterfaces {
  export interface MyInterface1 {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }
}

// index.ts
async function importMyInterfaces() {
  const {MyInterfaces} = await import("./MyInterfaces");
  const data1: MyInterfaces.MyInterface1 = {
    id: 1,
    name: "John Doe",
  };
}
```

TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'MyInterfaces'.

My tsconfig is set as follows with node 18:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to dynamically import interfaces to reduce the cold start time of Firebase functions. Because all the type information will already be stripped away when TypeScript code is transpiled to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyInterface1` was a `default` export, then you could asynchronously import and find the `typeof` within the `importMyInterfaces()` call.

**MyInterfaces.ts**

```
export default interface MyInterface1 {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
async function importMyInterfaces() {
  const MyInterface1 = await import("./MyInterfaces");
  const data1: typeof MyInterface1 = {
    id: 1,
    name: "John Doe"
  };
  console.log("data1", data1);
}
```

If you don't need to import asynchronously, then you can simply import at the top of index.ts.

**MyInterfaces.ts**

```
export interface MyInterface1 {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import { MyInterface1 } from './MyInterfaces';

async function importMyInterfaces() {
  const data1: MyInterface1 = {
    id: 1,
    name: "John Doe",
  };
}
```

Comment: Gives the error TS2749: 'MyInterface1' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MyInterface1'? -> https://imgur.com/Etp6cBQ

Comment: I also tried wrapping the type in InstanceType<typeof MyInterface1> but that presents another error instead: Property 'MyInterface1' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Users/ramsa/IdeaProjects/lets_hang/functions/src/MyInterfaces")'.

Comment: Apologies I made a mistaken edit -- The import for your interface does not need to happen asynchronously. You should just import it at the top of your `index.ts` file, then simply use it inside the async call.

Comment: I need it to be done asynchronously because this is a firebase cloud function so I need the import statements not to be done in global scope or it will increase the cold start time of all other functions that dont need this import

Comment: Are you running all your Firebase functions and their imports from the same `index.ts`? Then I understand why that would be a problem. Why not make each function it's own module so the modules have separated imports? `.https.onCall(async (data, context) => doCall(data, context))`

Comment: Yes. I will try to break all the functions into separate files and dynamically import/call them, but I still would like to know how to dynamically import types.

Comment: Sure it's possible if the interface is a default export. Then you can do `typeof` on the imported module. Revised the answer to include that.

Comment: While this removes the errors, the issue now becomes that there is no type information provided at all and refactoring support which negates the benefit of importing the type as seen in the picture https://imgur.com/hvN24pA is this an issue with my IDE or do you too not get any type info?